# Simplest means to fade/dissolve between two UIImageViews

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview

Could someone give me a little direction on creating crossfades/dissolves between two UIImageViews in the same view controller? I am trying to set up an effect of a background image slideshow but not sure on the mechanics. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is to do two alpha fades:

```
//set up two image views, view1 and view2
view1.alpha = 1.0;
view2.alpha = 0.0;
[myView addSubview: view1];
[myView addSubview: view2];
[UIView beginAnimation: nil context: nil];
view1.alpha = 0.0;
view2.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```